# My MacBook re-boots when going into sleep - tips for analyzing problems?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, reboot

since a few days my 2010 MacBook Pro re-boots on a regular basis. I'm looking for tips on how to diagnose the cause of the problem.

Usually my MacBook (running Mavericks) is sitting on my desk, plugged into power, a large screen, and a powered USB hub (which in turn usually just connects to my iPod). When I unplug it and close the lid, it doesn't go into sleep mode but instead re-boots after a few minutes. This has been consistently happening for about a weak.

I am unaware of any hardware or software changes that have recently occurred.

Which logs should I study? What other tools are there that may help me to pin down the problem?

Thanks for any helpful hints.

Thorsten

```
Output by pmset -g:
Listed by owning process:
   pid 1723(backupd): [0x000000010000048d] 00:02:50 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Time Machine backup" 
   pid 1723(backupd): [0x0000000c0000048c] 00:02:50 BackgroundTask named: "Time Machine backup" 
   pid 49(hidd): [0x0000000a00000499] 00:01:35 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
    Timeout will fire in 261 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
Kernel Assertions: 0x10c=USB,BT-HID,MAGICWAKE
   id=500  level=255 0x4=USB mod=15.05.14 19:32 description=EHC1 owner=AppleUSBEHCI
   id=504  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=15.05.14 23:04 description=en1 owner=en1
   id=505  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01.01.70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=BNBMouseDevice
   id=506  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01.01.70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard
```

Some more logs after it happened again:

```
May 17 12:35:21 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box usernoted[218]: Connection does not have the proper entitlement (com.apple.developer.notificationcenter-identifiers) to connect on behalf of com.apple.appstore. All communication will be denied.
May 17 12:35:21 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mDNSResponder[37]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FC30C013560 Thorstens-MacBook.local. (AAAA) that's already in the list
May 17 12:35:21 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mDNSResponder[37]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FC30C0139F0 1.9.E.F.7.9.E.F.F.F.E.5.2.A.A.D.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.E.F.ip6.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
May 17 12:35:21 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mDNSResponder[37]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FC30C824F60 Thorstens-MacBook.local. (Addr) that's already in the list
May 17 12:35:21 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mDNSResponder[37]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FC30C8253F0 104.178.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
May 17 12:35:22 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box com.apple.usbmuxd[17]: LOCKDOWN_V2_BONJOUR_SERVICE_NAME is _apple-mobdev2._tcp,8bf7078d
May 17 12:35:22 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box com.apple.usbmuxd[17]: _SendAttachNotification Device 9c:04:eb:9d:61:ba@fe80::9e04:ebff:fe9d:61ba._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local. has already appeared on interface 5. Suppressing duplicate attach notification.
May 17 12:35:23 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box sandboxd[334] ([458]): bookstoreagent(458) deny file-read-data /Users/tr/Library/Preferences/com.apple.WebFoundation.plist
May 17 12:35:28 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:35:35 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box xpcd[196]: restored permissions (100600 -> 100700) on /Users/tr/Library/Containers/com.apple.MediaLibraryService/Container.plist
May 17 12:35:37 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:35:38 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
May 17 12:35:38 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box iTunes[201]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
May 17 12:35:41 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:35:41 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
May 17 12:35:41 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box com.apple.SecurityServer[25]: Session 100019 created
May 17 12:35:42 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:35:50 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
May 17 12:35:50 thorstesmacbook kernel[0]: process WindowServer[92] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 151; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 70949
May 17 12:35:50 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box ReportCrash[464]: Invoking spindump for pid=92 wakeups_rate=151 duration=299 because of excessive wakeups
May 17 12:35:51 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box iTunes[201]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:1
May 17 12:35:51 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box iTunes[201]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:1
May 17 12:35:51 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box iTunes[201]: tid:11b13 - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
May 17 12:35:51 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box iTunes[201]: tid:11b13 - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
May 17 12:35:58 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:36:07 thorstesmacbook kernel[0]: process com.apple.WebKit[318] caught causing excessive wakeups. Observed wakeups rate (per sec): 266; Maximum permitted wakeups rate (per sec): 150; Observation period: 300 seconds; Task lifetime number of wakeups: 76338
May 17 12:36:07 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box ReportCrash[469]: Invoking spindump for pid=318 wakeups_rate=266 duration=170 because of excessive wakeups
May 17 12:36:09 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
May 17 12:36:39 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
May 17 12:36:58 thorstesmacbook.fritz.box mds[36]: (Warning) Server: No stores registered for metascope "kMDQueryScopeComputer"
```

And the updated pmset output:

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   PreventDiskIdle                0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   InteractivePushServiceTask     0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  1
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            1
Listed by owning process:
   pid 28(powerd): [0x0000000900000190] 00:09:29 ExternalMedia named: "com.apple.powermanagement.externalmediamounted" 
   pid 45(hidd): [0x0000000a00000198] 00:05:45 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle" 
    Timeout will fire in 276 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 136(mds_stores): [0x0000000c000001be] 00:03:16 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power" 
   pid 201(iTunes): [0x00000012000001c3] 00:00:02 NetworkClientActive named: "com.apple.iTunes.server" 
   pid 36(mds): [0x0000000c000001bd] 00:03:16 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power" 
Kernel Assertions: 0xc=USB,BT-HID
   id=500  level=255 0x4=USB mod=17.05.14 12:35 description=EHC1 owner=AppleUSBEHCI
   id=504  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01.01.70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=BNBMouseDevice
   id=505  level=255 0x8=BT-HID mod=01.01.70 01:00 description=com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver owner=AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard
```

Comment: I was hoping for more lines trying to discover what makes it shut down and restart.

Comment: next time it happens, instead of `pmset` try `tail -n30 /private/var/log/system.log` and paste the log after you get logged back in, and maybe that will give Buscar웃 what he needs to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 simple tools to use:

- Open Console in the Utility.

Type `Wake Reason` in the search window.

That one will display who is waking up your computer.

.

- In Terminal (also in Utility folder)

Type `pmset -g assertions`

That one will tell you your sleep mode settings (and possibly show who is waking it up)

You can copy and paste that information in here if you want us to look at it.

Update:

Please disable the MagicWake and try without it!

You can do that with: Sytem Preferences, Energy Saver then uncheck the Wake For Ethernet network access, and the MAGICWAKE should disappear!

Comment: The problem occurs when the computer goes to sleep, not when it's waking up. Will the information still help?

Comment: to quote you: When I unplug it and close the lid, it doesn't go into sleep mode but instead re-boots after a few minute. So we are looking for what it wakes it up..(re-boot).That is what I answered.

Comment: I appreciate your help .. maybe my description wasn't clear :-) When I close the lid or unplug the cables, the computer locks up (instead of going to sleep). The reboot seems to be "automatic" ..

Comment: OK, that's new information :) could you still provide the information please.

Comment: Wake reason is usually EC LID0

Comment: @IronGoofy how is that possible if it restarts as you say. So when you open the Lid the computer restarts ?

Comment: When I open the lid, I can tell it has restarted. As usual with Mavericks, all apps are restarted as well, but you can tell from the open documents (and also some running services) that a restart has happened.